# How to use 'numeric' in Vuetify and vee validator if value is present and without using 'numeric|required'?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

In the below code I tried to achieve validation if validation rule is present like numeric but without required. validation code is not working if rules is 'numeric' but works if it is 'numeric|required'.

I read this issue on github
https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/383
but this doesn't seem to work.

Try 1-

```
<template>
<ValidationProvider
            ref="totalquantity"
            name="Stock Total Quantity"
            rules="numeric"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model.number="item"
              slot-scope="{
                errors,
                valid,
              }"
              clearable
              dense
              :error-messages="errors"
              :success="valid"
              label="Item*"
              type="number"
              outlined
            />
          </ValidationProvider>
</template>
<script>
import { ValidationProvider, extend } from 'vee-validate'
import { required, numeric, regex, integer } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
extend('required', required)
extend('numeric', numeric)
extend('regex', regex)
extend('integer', integer)
</script>
```

Try 2-

```
:rules="edititem.percustomerqty?'required|numeric':''"
```